# Sorting data from .txt file

Tags: python, mysql, sorting, parsing

I am running some query's on mysql through python. Once reading the data I would want to sort them by percentage. Any help would be gladly appriciated.

The method I am using to write is:

```
def mid_critical(controller,code):
critical = 75
mid_critical = 50

cursor = controller.cursor()
cursor.execute(code)    # execute code

with open('report.txt', 'a') as f:
    print("\n******************* Mid Critical: **************", file=f)
    for r in cursor:  #show tables one by one
        if str(type(r[5])) == "<class 'decimal.Decimal'>":
            percent = r[5] / r[2] * 100
            if percent > mid_critical and percent < critical:
                print(r[1],"\nOwner:",r[8],"\nValues:",r[5],"out of", r[2] ,"\nPercent used: %d%% \n" %(percent), file=f)
```

***code*** is the query that is being ran.

***controller*** is credentials to make a succesful communication.

Once writing to the file is:

```
POC 
Owner: ACE 
Values: 45.1 out of 81.5 
Percent used: 55% 

DESKTOP 
Owner: Nan 
Values: 231.8 out of 329.2 
Percent used: 70% 

REGRESSION 
Owner: None 
Values: 6.6 out of 10.2 
Percent used: 64%
```

For the sake of an example I only show 3, there is houndreds more.

The output I am seeking would be

```
DESKTOP 
Owner: Nan 
Values: 231.8 out of 329.2 
Percent used: 70% 

REGRESSION 
Owner: None 
Values: 6.6 out of 10.2 
Percent used: 64% 

POC 
Owner: ACE 
Values: 45.1 out of 81.5 
Percent used: 55%
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort the data, you need to get the data out of the database, sort it, then print it to the file instead of writing to the file after each row. Something like this:

```
def calc_percent(r):
    return r[5] / r[2] * 100

with open('report.txt', 'a') as f:
    print("\n******************* Mid Critical: **************", file=f)
    rows = []
    for r in cursor:  #show tables one by one
        if str(type(r[5])) == "<class 'decimal.Decimal'>":
            percent = calc_percent(r)
            if percent > mid_critical and percent < critical:
                rows.append(r)
    rows.sort(key=calc_percent)

    for r in rows:
        percent = calc_percent(r)
        print(r[1],"\nOwner:",r[8],"\nValues:",r[5],"out of", r[2] ,"\nPercent used: %d%% \n" %(percent), file=f)
```

Answer (score 1):

BigO.
Maybe you should consider calculating the percentage inside your MySQL Query and using ORDER BY to get the order right.

Then, on python you'll already have the records in the order you intended.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT Number1,Number2,Number1/Number2 AS Percentage
   FROM Table
) subquery
ORDER BY Percentage
```

Then do whatever you want with the data

Answer (score 1):

Append sections to a list, sort the list of lists by the last element, and then output the list:

```
from operator import itemgetter

report = []
for r in cursor:  # show tables one by one
    if str(type(r[5])) == "<class 'decimal.Decimal'>":
        percent = r[5] / r[2] * 100
        if percent > mid_critical and percent < critical:
            report.append(
                (
                    str(r[1]),
                    "\nOwner:",
                    str(r[8]),
                    "\nValues:",
                    str(r[5]),
                    "out of",
                    str(r[2]),
                    "\nPercent used: %d%% \n" % (percent),
                )
            )

report.sort(key=itemgetter(-1), reverse=True)

with open("report.txt", "a") as f:
    print("\n******************* Mid Critical: **************", file=f)
    print("\n".join(report))
```

Comment: Hello @ipaleka, the code works. Only issue is that the list goes from small to big. I would like it from big to small. As well the output does not come out correct. The output Im getting as of now is 
_('CVS_Functional', '\nOwner:', 'Retired', '\nValues:', Decimal('18.3'), 'out of', Decimal('31.8'), '\nPercent used: 57% \n')_

Comment: I added `reverse=True` for the first problem. And about the other problem, I added `str()`, but not sure why that 's happening in my code and not in yours.